# can i use one backend request for couple endpoints?

Tags: node.js, angular

```
http://localhost:4200/product-list?gender=2&category=4

http://localhost:4200/product-list?gender=2

http://localhost:4200/product-list?category=4
```

i want to use one backend controller for the endpoints.
can i do that? i tried but with no success. (using angular)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly did you try with angular? The backend controller? Angular is a frontend framework.

However, you could indeed have one single controller (e.g. ProductController) for your endpoints. I would suggest implementing a "getProducts" method that can be filterable. That way you can use single endpoint and provide optional filter options as needed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68734655/using-one-request-for-couple-url-endpoints-angular/68736344#68736344

ok. you can see my code there. right now when i am sending only one of the queryParams the default `req.params.gender` is 0 and thats not working, what can i do about it.

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand your question entirely, so please stat otherwise. But, Yes. You have one endpoint stated above, with different query params. Depending on the different query params (their value or even if they are present), your singular endpoint can do something different.

So your endpoint is

```
http://localhost:4200/product-list
```

This endpoint (which there is only one), can have as many query params as you like. As per the response above, Angular does not handle this, this would be some backend functionality for your end point, to read the request, and based on what query params are 'found' then trigger a different response.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68734655/using-one-request-for-couple-url-endpoints-angular/68736344#68736344

ok. you can see my code there. right now when i am sending only one of the queryParams the default `req.params.gender` is 0 and thats not working, what can i do about it.